# how to filter TRUE values from logical results of sapply?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I am new in R and to check whether a column has negative values or not I have used sapply()

```
sapply(dt1, FUN = function(x) all(x <= 0, na.rm = TRUE))

########## output ##########

                  SK_ID_CURR                       TARGET           NAME_CONTRACT_TYPE 
                       FALSE                        FALSE                        FALSE 
                 CODE_GENDER                 FLAG_OWN_CAR              FLAG_OWN_REALTY 
                       FALSE                        FALSE                        FALSE 
                CNT_CHILDREN             AMT_INCOME_TOTAL                   AMT_CREDIT 
                       FALSE                        FALSE                        FALSE 
                 AMT_ANNUITY              AMT_GOODS_PRICE              NAME_TYPE_SUITE 
                       FALSE                        FALSE                        FALSE 
            NAME_INCOME_TYPE          NAME_EDUCATION_TYPE           NAME_FAMILY_STATUS 
                       FALSE                        FALSE                        FALSE 
           NAME_HOUSING_TYPE   REGION_POPULATION_RELATIVE                   DAYS_BIRTH 
                       FALSE                        FALSE                         TRUE 
               DAYS_EMPLOYED            DAYS_REGISTRATION              DAYS_ID_PUBLISH 
                        TRUE                         TRUE                         TRUE 
                 OWN_CAR_AGE                   FLAG_MOBIL               FLAG_EMP_PHONE 
                       FALSE                        FALSE                        FALSE 
             FLAG_WORK_PHONE             FLAG_CONT_MOBILE                   FLAG_PHONE 
                       FALSE                        FALSE                        FALSE 
                  FLAG_EMAIL              OCCUPATION_TYPE              CNT_FAM_MEMBERS 
                       FALSE                        FALSE                        FALSE
```

I want to filter only the `TRUE` one's from these & have tried:

```
dt1[,sapply(dt1, FUN = function(x) all(x <= 0, na.rm = TRUE)) == TRUE]
```

but this didn't give what I expected and got the same results as earlier ones.

I even tried below code but that also didn't help:

```
dt1[,lapply(dt1, FUN = function(x) all(x <= 0, na.rm = TRUE)) == TRUE]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `== TRUE`. With dataframe this should have worked.

```
dt1[, sapply(dt1, FUN = function(x) all(x <= 0, na.rm = TRUE))]
```

But I think you have `data.table`, try to add `with = FALSE`.

```
library(data.table)
dt1[, sapply(dt1, FUN = function(x) all(x <= 0, na.rm = TRUE)), with = FALSE]
```

Comment: thanks @Ronak Shah, I tried this `dt1[, sapply(dt1, FUN = function(x) all(x <= 0, na.rm = TRUE))]` but got an error. But as you said to add `with = FALSE` then it worked. With all these small things R is actually getting painful. If you know any good source to learn then please let me know as well. Will accept the answer as soon as it let me !!

Comment: I would suggest that you first decide what path you want to take further. Broadly, there are 3 options. 1) Base R 2) Tidyverse 3) data.table. Select one of these method and try to focus on it. There are some minor syntax difference between 1, 2 and 3 which you can learn later.

Comment: I have mostly used 1 & 2 options and rarely used `data.table`. I think `r` is incomplete without `tidyverse` as `tidymodel`, `modeltime` & alot of its growth seems to be directed using `tidyverse` so I guess its better to stick with first two only. Thanks for your reply !!

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`, we can use

```
library(data.table)
dt1[, dt1[,  !colSums(.SD > 0)], with = FALSE]
```

---

Or using `select`

```
library(dplyr)
dt1 %>%
    select(where(~all(. <= 0))
```

Comment: thanks @akrun, I normally don't use `data.table` and didn't know it will alter the basic r functionality and will need to use `,with = FALSE` . Thanks again for the solution!!